# What's this hammer drill accessory and what does it do?

Tags: drill

Can anyone tell me how is the accessory in the picture called and what's its purpose?

[image: drill accessory]
http://storage9.static.itmages.com/i/17/0228/h_1488307031_8180005_c15fb41395.png

Thanks

Comment: I believe it's a drywall ratchet.  If set properly, it will slip just when the drywall screw is flush with the surface, stopping you from going deeper.

Comment: Thanks. I seem to see them quite often in DIY videos and it's not always about drywalls. e.g.  http://storage2.static.itmages.com/i/17/0228/h_1488309649_4466944_db0cad5648.png

Comment: It really just looks like a magnetic bit holder that allows a little flexion.

Comment: All the drywall type adapters I have for screw guns have a ridge to dimple the paper/ push the bit out. Those work well when I don't have my drywall drill. I would think @Hari Ganti has a better guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is a bit holder made by a company called Wera: [Rapidaptor Bit Holders](http://www-us.wera.de/catalog_us.html?L=1&file=/en-US/tools_for_power_use_holders_adaptors_connectors_rapidaptor_bit_holders.html)

I think it's [897/4 R Rapidaptor BiTorsion universal bit holder](http://www-us.wera.de/product_detail_us.html?L=1&file=tools_for_power_use_holders_adaptors_connectors_rapidaptor_bit_holders_897_4_r&lang=en-US) on that page.